# strsplit with rbind in R fills missing columns automatically

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny

strsplit with rbind in R fills missing columns automatically.
I want NA in case of missing columns because both the column names & column number is unknown
Below is the sample input:

```
1660|ABC|Urban|const|ABC|1660|ABC-23_Girvan|MultiPolygon (((-4.8066907 55.04347151, -4.80276148 55.04454913, -4.80273576 55.04455619, -4.80272906 55.0445397, -4.8019362 55.04259356, -4.80144005 55.04137563, -4.80143642 55.04136669, -4.80143318 55.04136487, -4.79932797 55.04017957, -4.79603597 55.03832586, -4.79602477 55.03831956, -4.79602909 55.03830962, -4.79681797 55.03648828, -4.79736311 55.0352296, -4.79736682 55.03522103, -4.79737054 55.03521246, -4.79734694 55.03519212, -4.79442154 55.03266764, -4.79436702 55.03262058, -4.79429576 55.032635, -4.79012226 55.03347964, -4.79007062 55.03349009, -4.78999373 55.03356092, -4.78954942 55.03397026, -4.78945452 55.03396611, -4.78523126 55.03378099, -4.78474862 55.03585432, -4.78410562 55.03755613, -4.78131992 55.03769417, -4.77995653 55.03933729, -4.7781591 55.04093226, -4.77183228 55.03970088, -4.77169854 55.03967882, -4.76459029 55.03850547, -4.76218988 55.03966093, -4.76218404 55.03966375, -4.76216777 55.03967074, -4.76208001 55.03970845, -4.75859975 55.03906771, -4.7524626 55.04284217, -4.7463334 55.04429135, -4.74314492 55.04672472, -4.74144307 55.04822486, -4.74077155 55.04822731, -4.74042671 55.04785351, -4.73920006 55.04652378, -4.73823528 55.04516571, -4.73819305 55.04511062, -4.73818743 55.04510704, -4.73738004 55.04459257, -4.73737984 55.04459012, -4.73729138 55.04348033, -4.73404678 55.0427649, -4.73162755 55.04424351, -4.72684084 55.04622438, -4.72454247 55.0462497, -4.72419217 55.04606356, -4.72258998 55.04538684, -4.72258924 55.04538653, -4.72258871 55.04538461, -4.72235393 55.04454127, -4.72220504 55.04400487, -4.72219207 55.04395817, -4.72215619 55.04393533, -4.72058722 55.04293649, -4.72057629 55.04292953, -4.72024656 55.04287095, -4.72024615 55.04287087, -4.72024571 55.0428708, -4.71960906 55.04275791, -4.71960096 55.04274676, -4.71872616 55.04154264, -4.71859094 55.04135649, -4.71824434 55.04082598, -4.71821688 55.04077155, -4.71791095 55.0401652, -4.71788206 55.04011276, -4.71787802 55.04010957, -4.71722657 55.03959414, -4.71540401 55.03999767, -4.71538959 55.04000086, -4.71487796 55.04025596, -4.71443494 55.03989911, -4.6918896 55.04502024, -4.69187352 55.04502389, -4.68493194 55.04330826, -4.68485827 55.04330196, -4.68484986 55.04331181, -4.68281241 55.04569817, -4.68274628 55.04570207, -4.67796529 55.04598422, -4.67578179 55.04884382, -4.67396727 55.05046258, -4.67239289 55.05062117, -4.67207876 55.05062863, -4.67145075 55.05064354, -4.67135174 55.05067477, -4.67083231 55.0508386, -4.67050812 55.05090876, -4.67020746 55.05097384, -4.66989921 55.05104055, -4.6692961 55.05105565, -4.6692866 55.05105588, -4.66928375 55.05105675, -4.66870015 55.05123527, -4.66865176 55.05125052, -4.66847284 55.05141605, -4.66821431 55.0516552, -4.6598276 55.0539769, -4.65904234 55.05348943, -4.65899383 55.05345932, -4.65895686 55.05347453, -4.65713805 55.0542235, -4.65541219 55.05510604, -4.64918418 55.05654281, -4.64529045 55.05746473, -4.64472591 55.05740647, -4.64454119 55.05540513, -4.64597245 55.05372462, -4.64620866 55.05173229, -4.64481074 55.0506421, -4.6444775 55.05038221, -4.64067873 55.05173855, -4.63732431 55.05211035, -4.63358558 55.05256525, -4.63336187 55.05388239, -4.63337637 55.05575676, -4.6329212 55.05646996, -4.63148884 55.05659632, -4.62928993 55.05736526, -4.6273795 55.05758632, -4.62386505 55.05783972, -4.62063736 55.0575441, -4.61845101 55.05867326, -4.61688535 55.05942835, -4.61469633 55.06055804, -4.61215512 55.06115143, -4.6086278 55.06140072, -4.61068485 55.06371569, -4.6145987 55.06472496, -4.6178753 55.06592646, -4.62214499 55.06783014, -4.62384362 55.06978576, -4.62435655 55.07070437, -4.62308292 55.07251163, -4.62535069 55.07251111, -4.62665101 55.07515748, -4.62832449 55.07617534, -4.62740353 55.07789383, -4.63292986 55.08032549, -4.63636727 55.07929898, -4.63674717 55.08035457, -4.63597826 55.08579344, -4.63208926 55.09491179, -4.62966443 55.10145779, -4.62555688 55.12333185, -4.62453006 55.1264075, -4.62308495 55.12787298, -4.61804869 55.13120733, -4.6118031 55.13473534, -4.60906361 55.13760085, -4.60737243 55.14124439, -4.60729076 55.14142037, -4.60728565 55.14308823, -4.60728565 55.14308823, -4.60288497 55.14207939, -4.59554115 55.14069688, -4.59311992 55.14314738, -4.58945406 55.14296188, -4.58688111 55.14342821, -4.58565648 55.14532862, -4.58217713 55.14502652, -4.57473495 55.14578197, -4.57715915 55.14850591, -4.57255628 55.15058907, -4.57241801 55.15306662, -4.57060383 55.1575286, -4.56503363 55.15633224, -4.56497722 55.15817053, -4.56450719 55.15971754, -4.56253598 55.16039597, -4.55886596 55.15930976, -4.55401746 55.16075999, -4.54797659 55.16110981, -4.5408484 55.16088173, -4.5369834 55.15979893, -4.53252787 55.16054235, -4.53143396 55.16070717, -4.51799229 55.15707571, -4.51271254 55.15362149, -4.50458987 55.15491117, -4.49940285 55.1544539, -4.47472464 55.15592548, -4.47382559 55.15789315, -4.47166113 55.15951106, -4.46809419 55.15890751, -4.46608368 55.15995999, -4.46179496 55.16375731, -4.45882785 55.16869028, -4.45995621 55.17162983, -4.45685079 55.17289131, -4.45143386 55.17198661, -4.44301984 55.1702411, -4.44306281 55.16724087, -4.44288324 55.16476994, -4.4446801 55.16345964, -4.44554009 55.16183049, -4.44485583 55.16049424, -4.43952776 55.15808756, -4.43976355 55.1496472, -4.43755762 55.14335338, -4.43805226 55.14283349, -4.57473486 55.14578185, -4.60588908 55.07343634, -4.59519957 55.06233673, -4.60013217 55.06077222, -4.58944762 55.04967193, -4.58979889 55.04956051, -4.60742485 55.0511097, -4.60742485 55.05110969, -4.60742504 55.0511097, -4.60751859 55.05075858, -4.60818492 55.05109407, -4.608185 55.05109402, -4.60818511 55.05109407, -4.62479165 55.04021827, -4.62507206 55.04295189, -4.62507226 55.04295188, -4.62507226 55.0429519, -4.63288233 55.04268746, -4.63071659 55.02160371, -4.64992574 55.04154173, -4.64992589 55.04154168, -4.64992594 55.04154173, -4.65485366 55.03997507, -4.65572824 55.04088217, -4.65572834 55.04088214, -4.65572838 55.04088218, -4.66257217 55.03870582, -4.66055361 55.0366125, -4.66548053 55.03504536, -4.66346206 55.03295215, -4.66838841 55.03138489, -4.65562524 55.01814485, -4.66790927 55.01520004, -4.66595911 55.01785411, -4.72205117 55.03144487, -4.72205119 55.03144484, -4.72205135 55.03144487, -4.72508752 55.02730471, -4.72508752 55.02730471, -4.72727318 55.02432375, -4.83764211 54.99347404, -4.8391614 54.99347765, -4.84818311 54.99349909, -4.8538311 54.99932518, -4.80669355 55.04346885, -4.8066907 55.04347151))|Pnt (-4.65723857 55.07320805)|||
1552|ABC|Urban|const|ABC|1552|ABC-23_Girvan|MultiPolygon (((-4.27763349 55.3106471, -4.27809894 55.31053055, -4.28715259 55.30983888, -4.29059196 55.31033773, -4.29705406 55.31287996, -4.29825773 55.31022995, -4.29915871 55.31080432, -4.3040445 55.31063359, -4.32196403 55.30841057, -4.35013465 55.30337916, -4.35608607 55.30381051, -4.36029362 55.30259222, -4.36348063 55.30099468, -4.36629835 55.29901995, -4.36777166 55.29666621, -4.36854792 55.29393497, -4.36859387 55.29046006, -4.36444536 55.27604388, -4.36310057 55.27124315, -4.36296541 55.27076095, -4.36290831 55.27021376, -4.36010948 55.26458948, -4.35921514 55.2627564, -4.35605039 55.25626822, -4.35456341 55.25080791, -4.35539054 55.24894911, -4.35797725 55.24485067, -4.35873852 55.24082456, -4.3592542 55.23702803, -4.36225353 55.23415897, -4.36549236 55.23098519, -4.36801163 55.22688783, -4.37341748 55.221123, -4.37385869 55.21721542, -4.37523926 55.21366483, -4.3793209 55.2104371, -4.38160336 55.20671897, -4.3877229 55.204614, -4.38954584 55.20262034, -4.39093331 55.20110279, -4.39231314 55.19665216, -4.39260793 55.19589522, -4.39380369 55.19564477, -4.39652619 55.19507449, -4.40571406 55.19426214, -4.41280656 55.19434166, -4.41869148 55.19478236, -4.42677958 55.19588568, -4.43924456 55.19779309, -4.44834509 55.19939003, -4.45205979 55.20004164, -4.46744208 55.20312624, -4.46992825 55.20353096, -4.46926582 55.20713926, -4.46942315 55.20942647, -4.4696447 55.21260001, -4.47045278 55.21524371, -4.4715235 55.21718096, -4.47293288 55.21947482, -4.47572079 55.22354572, -4.47812634 55.22656423, -4.48298204 55.23604339, -4.48339424 55.23712038, -4.4835154 55.23838193, -4.48391374 55.23927942, -4.48464117 55.24035335, -4.48664623 55.24177203, -4.48803303 55.24319935, -4.48880194 55.24463532, -4.48814179 55.24717571, -4.48656682 55.24972967, -4.48588827 55.25191147, -4.48554678 55.25427066, -4.48464194 55.25700088, -4.48341866 55.25955612, -4.48126257 55.26194436, -4.47822172 55.26452863, -4.47488634 55.26711767, -4.47115682 55.26898763, -4.47084436 55.26910913, -4.46970303 55.26955302, -4.46682164 55.27086635, -4.46490688 55.27252975, -4.46388379 55.27399928, -4.46402284 55.27727229, -4.46597052 55.28033742, -4.46811244 55.28248736, -4.47054703 55.28444876, -4.47407458 55.28747954, -4.47681134 55.28924873, -4.48081946 55.29117462, -4.48491314 55.29364022, -4.49071678 55.29715731, -4.49389421 55.29981433, -4.49578891 55.30231379, -4.49675655 55.30501139, -4.49776705 55.30825135, -4.49833939 55.31059465, -4.50014046 55.31291222, -4.50202214 55.31631459, -4.50542276 55.31968523, -4.51009609 55.32393858, -4.51441426 55.32820807, -4.51834953 55.33176287, -4.52164867 55.33551663, -4.52584909 55.33870505, -4.52849713 55.3424766, -4.53244048 55.34767851, -4.53507095 55.35126714, -4.53535285 55.35164433, -4.53868897 55.3561076, -4.54165075 55.35986615, -4.54364242 55.36273418, -4.54404772 55.3654532, -4.54421522 55.3659913, -4.54511516 55.36888201, -4.54602098 55.3699382, -4.52896118 55.37263801, -4.50087758 55.35824432, -4.47661559 55.37139693, -4.44762781 55.38682775, -4.32023047 55.33238024, -4.27301552 55.31545439, -4.27763349 55.3106471)))|Point (-4.42368856 55.2960241)|||
1625|ABC|Urban|const|ABC|1625|ABC-23_Girvan|MultiPolygon (((-4.6 55.07929898, -4.63292986 55.08032549, -4.62740353 55.07789383, -4.62832449 55.07617534, -4.62894805 55.07655459, -4.63067565 55.07719054, -4.63218879 55.07774751, -4.63603734 55.0783822, -4.63636727 55.07929898)))|Point (-4.63175565 55.0784619)|||
```

And my code is:

```
df.new1 = as.data.frame(lapply(MA_in, function(x) do.call(rbind, strsplit(as.character(x), ",", fixed = TRUE))))
```

where MA_in is the column with values MultiPolygon (((-4.806--------- as shown in the sample dataframe, this gives me the dataframe with rbind filling in NA with automatic previous values
Can i get the dataframe output with NA for missing column values as:

```
1660|ABC|Urban|const|ABC|1660|ABC-23_Girvan|col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7 and so on...
1552|ABC|Urban|const|ABC|1552|ABC-23_Girvan|col1  NA    NA   NA   NA NA
1625|ABC|Urban|const|ABC|1625|ABC-23_Girvan|col1 col2   NA   NA   NA NA
```

dput output

```
structure(list(Id = c(1660L, 1552L, 1625L), Coverage = c("MultiPolygon (((-4.8066907 55.04347151, -4.80276148 55.04454913, -4.80273576 55.04455619, -4.80272906 55.0445397, -4.8019362 55.04259356, -4.80144005 55.04137563, -4.80143642 55.04136669, -4.80143318 55.04136487, -4.79932797 55.04017957, -4.79603597 55.03832586, -4.79602477 55.03831956, -4.79602909 55.03830962, -4.79681797 55.03648828, -4.79736311 55.0352296, -4.79736682 55.03522103, -4.79737054 55.03521246, -4.79734694 55.03519212, -4.79442154 55.03266764, -4.79436702 55.03262058, -4.79429576 55.032635, -4.79012226 55.03347964, -4.79007062 55.03349009, -4.78999373 55.03356092, -4.78954942 55.03397026, -4.78945452 55.03396611, -4.78523126 55.03378099, -4.78474862 55.03585432, -4.78410562 55.03755613, -4.78131992 55.03769417, -4.77995653 55.03933729, -4.7781591 55.04093226, -4.77183228 55.03970088, -4.77169854 55.03967882, -4.76459029 55.03850547, -4.76218988 55.03966093, -4.76218404 55.03966375, -4.76216777 55.03967074, -4.76208001 55.03970845, -4.75859975 55.03906771, -4.7524626 55.04284217, -4.7463334 55.04429135, -4.74314492 55.04672472, -4.74144307 55.04822486, -4.74077155 55.04822731, -4.74042671 55.04785351, -4.73920006 55.04652378, -4.73823528 55.04516571, -4.73819305 55.04511062, -4.73818743 55.04510704, -4.73738004 55.04459257, -4.73737984 55.04459012, -4.73729138 55.04348033, -4.73404678 55.0427649, -4.73162755 55.04424351, -4.72684084 55.04622438, -4.72454247 55.0462497, -4.72419217 55.04606356, -4.72258998 55.04538684, -4.72258924 55.04538653, -4.72258871 55.04538461, -4.72235393 55.04454127, -4.72220504 55.04400487, -4.72219207 55.04395817, -4.72215619 55.04393533, -4.72058722 55.04293649, -4.72057629 55.04292953, -4.72024656 55.04287095, -4.72024615 55.04287087, -4.72024571 55.0428708, -4.71960906 55.04275791, -4.71960096 55.04274676, -4.71872616 55.04154264, -4.71859094 55.04135649, -4.71824434 55.04082598, -4.71821688 55.04077155, -4.71791095 55.0401652, -4.71788206 55.04011276, -4.71787802 55.04010957, -4.71722657 55.03959414, -4.71540401 55.03999767, -4.71538959 55.04000086, -4.71487796 55.04025596, -4.71443494 55.03989911, -4.6918896 55.04502024, -4.69187352 55.04502389, -4.68493194 55.04330826, -4.68485827 55.04330196, -4.68484986 55.04331181, -4.68281241 55.04569817, -4.68274628 55.04570207, -4.67796529 55.04598422, -4.67578179 55.04884382, -4.67396727 55.05046258, -4.67239289 55.05062117, -4.67207876 55.05062863, -4.67145075 55.05064354, -4.67135174 55.05067477, -4.67083231 55.0508386, -4.67050812 55.05090876, -4.67020746 55.05097384, -4.66989921 55.05104055, -4.6692961 55.05105565, -4.6692866 55.05105588, -4.66928375 55.05105675, -4.66870015 55.05123527, -4.66865176 55.05125052, -4.66847284 55.05141605, -4.66821431 55.0516552, -4.6598276 55.0539769, -4.65904234 55.05348943, -4.65899383 55.05345932, -4.65895686 55.05347453, -4.65713805 55.0542235, -4.65541219 55.05510604, -4.64918418 55.05654281, -4.64529045 55.05746473, -4.64472591 55.05740647, -4.64454119 55.05540513, -4.64597245 55.05372462, -4.64620866 55.05173229, -4.64481074 55.0506421, -4.6444775 55.05038221, -4.64067873 55.05173855, -4.63732431 55.05211035, -4.63358558 55.05256525, -4.63336187 55.05388239, -4.63337637 55.05575676, -4.6329212 55.05646996, -4.63148884 55.05659632, -4.62928993 55.05736526, -4.6273795 55.05758632, -4.62386505 55.05783972, -4.62063736 55.0575441, -4.61845101 55.05867326, -4.61688535 55.05942835, -4.61469633 55.06055804, -4.61215512 55.06115143, -4.6086278 55.06140072, -4.61068485 55.06371569, -4.6145987 55.06472496, -4.6178753 55.06592646, -4.62214499 55.06783014, -4.62384362 55.06978576, -4.62435655 55.07070437, -4.62308292 55.07251163, -4.62535069 55.07251111, -4.62665101 55.07515748, -4.62832449 55.07617534, -4.62740353 55.07789383, -4.63292986 55.08032549, -4.63636727 55.07929898, -4.63674717 55.08035457, -4.63597826 55.08579344, -4.63208926 55.09491179, -4.62966443 55.10145779, -4.62555688 55.12333185, -4.62453006 55.1264075, -4.62308495 55.12787298, -4.61804869 55.13120733, -4.6118031 55.13473534, -4.60906361 55.13760085, -4.60737243 55.14124439, -4.60729076 55.14142037, -4.60728565 55.14308823, -4.60728565 55.14308823, -4.60288497 55.14207939, -4.59554115 55.14069688, -4.59311992 55.14314738, -4.58945406 55.14296188, -4.58688111 55.14342821, -4.58565648 55.14532862, -4.58217713 55.14502652, -4.57473495 55.14578197, -4.57715915 55.14850591, -4.57255628 55.15058907, -4.57241801 55.15306662, -4.57060383 55.1575286, -4.56503363 55.15633224, -4.56497722 55.15817053, -4.56450719 55.15971754, -4.56253598 55.16039597, -4.55886596 55.15930976, -4.55401746 55.16075999, -4.54797659 55.16110981, -4.5408484 55.16088173, -4.5369834 55.15979893, -4.53252787 55.16054235, -4.53143396 55.16070717, -4.51799229 55.15707571, -4.51271254 55.15362149, -4.50458987 55.15491117, -4.49940285 55.1544539, -4.47472464 55.15592548, -4.47382559 55.15789315, -4.47166113 55.15951106, -4.46809419 55.15890751, -4.46608368 55.15995999, -4.46179496 55.16375731, -4.45882785 55.16869028, -4.45995621 55.17162983, -4.45685079 55.17289131, -4.45143386 55.17198661, -4.44301984 55.1702411, -4.44306281 55.16724087, -4.44288324 55.16476994, -4.4446801 55.16345964, -4.44554009 55.16183049, -4.44485583 55.16049424, -4.43952776 55.15808756, -4.43976355 55.1496472, -4.43755762 55.14335338, -4.43805226 55.14283349, -4.57473486 55.14578185, -4.60588908 55.07343634, -4.59519957 55.06233673, -4.60013217 55.06077222, -4.58944762 55.04967193, -4.58979889 55.04956051, -4.60742485 55.0511097, -4.60742485 55.05110969, -4.60742504 55.0511097, -4.60751859 55.05075858, -4.60818492 55.05109407, -4.608185 55.05109402, -4.60818511 55.05109407, -4.62479165 55.04021827, -4.62507206 55.04295189, -4.62507226 55.04295188, -4.62507226 55.0429519, -4.63288233 55.04268746, -4.63071659 55.02160371, -4.64992574 55.04154173, -4.64992589 55.04154168, -4.64992594 55.04154173, -4.65485366 55.03997507, -4.65572824 55.04088217, -4.65572834 55.04088214, -4.65572838 55.04088218, -4.66257217 55.03870582, -4.66055361 55.0366125, -4.66548053 55.03504536, -4.66346206 55.03295215, -4.66838841 55.03138489, -4.65562524 55.01814485, -4.66790927 55.01520004, -4.66595911 55.01785411, -4.72205117 55.03144487, -4.72205119 55.03144484, -4.72205135 55.03144487, -4.72508752 55.02730471, -4.72508752 55.02730471, -4.72727318 55.02432375, -4.83764211 54.99347404, -4.8391614 54.99347765, -4.84818311 54.99349909, -4.8538311 54.99932518, -4.80669355 55.04346885, -4.8066907 55.04347151))", 
"MultiPolygon (((-4.27763349 55.3106471, -4.27809894 55.31053055, -4.28715259 55.30983888, -4.29059196 55.31033773, -4.29705406 55.31287996, -4.29825773 55.31022995, -4.29915871 55.31080432, -4.3040445 55.31063359, -4.32196403 55.30841057, -4.35013465 55.30337916, -4.35608607 55.30381051, -4.36029362 55.30259222, -4.36348063 55.30099468, -4.36629835 55.29901995, -4.36777166 55.29666621, -4.36854792 55.29393497, -4.36859387 55.29046006, -4.36444536 55.27604388, -4.36310057 55.27124315, -4.36296541 55.27076095, -4.36290831 55.27021376, -4.36010948 55.26458948, -4.35921514 55.2627564, -4.35605039 55.25626822, -4.35456341 55.25080791, -4.35539054 55.24894911, -4.35797725 55.24485067, -4.35873852 55.24082456, -4.3592542 55.23702803, -4.36225353 55.23415897, -4.36549236 55.23098519, -4.36801163 55.22688783, -4.37341748 55.221123, -4.37385869 55.21721542, -4.37523926 55.21366483, -4.3793209 55.2104371, -4.38160336 55.20671897, -4.3877229 55.204614, -4.38954584 55.20262034, -4.39093331 55.20110279, -4.39231314 55.19665216, -4.39260793 55.19589522, -4.39380369 55.19564477, -4.39652619 55.19507449, -4.40571406 55.19426214, -4.41280656 55.19434166, -4.41869148 55.19478236, -4.42677958 55.19588568, -4.43924456 55.19779309, -4.44834509 55.19939003, -4.45205979 55.20004164, -4.46744208 55.20312624, -4.46992825 55.20353096, -4.46926582 55.20713926, -4.46942315 55.20942647, -4.4696447 55.21260001, -4.47045278 55.21524371, -4.4715235 55.21718096, -4.47293288 55.21947482, -4.47572079 55.22354572, -4.47812634 55.22656423, -4.48298204 55.23604339, -4.48339424 55.23712038, -4.4835154 55.23838193, -4.48391374 55.23927942, -4.48464117 55.24035335, -4.48664623 55.24177203, -4.48803303 55.24319935, -4.48880194 55.24463532, -4.48814179 55.24717571, -4.48656682 55.24972967, -4.48588827 55.25191147, -4.48554678 55.25427066, -4.48464194 55.25700088, -4.48341866 55.25955612, -4.48126257 55.26194436, -4.47822172 55.26452863, -4.47488634 55.26711767, -4.47115682 55.26898763, -4.47084436 55.26910913, -4.46970303 55.26955302, -4.46682164 55.27086635, -4.46490688 55.27252975, -4.46388379 55.27399928, -4.46402284 55.27727229, -4.46597052 55.28033742, -4.46811244 55.28248736, -4.47054703 55.28444876, -4.47407458 55.28747954, -4.47681134 55.28924873, -4.48081946 55.29117462, -4.48491314 55.29364022, -4.49071678 55.29715731, -4.49389421 55.29981433, -4.49578891 55.30231379, -4.49675655 55.30501139, -4.49776705 55.30825135, -4.49833939 55.31059465, -4.50014046 55.31291222, -4.50202214 55.31631459, -4.50542276 55.31968523, -4.51009609 55.32393858, -4.51441426 55.32820807, -4.51834953 55.33176287, -4.52164867 55.33551663, -4.52584909 55.33870505, -4.52849713 55.3424766, -4.53244048 55.34767851, -4.53507095 55.35126714, -4.53535285 55.35164433, -4.53868897 55.3561076, -4.54165075 55.35986615, -4.54364242 55.36273418, -4.54404772 55.3654532, -4.54421522 55.3659913, -4.54511516 55.36888201, -4.54602098 55.3699382, -4.52896118 55.37263801, -4.50087758 55.35824432, -4.47661559 55.37139693, -4.44762781 55.38682775, -4.32023047 55.33238024, -4.27301552 55.31545439, -4.27763349 55.3106471)))", 
"MultiPolygon (((-4.6 55.07929898, -4.63292986 55.08032549, -4.62740353 55.07789383, -4.62832449 55.07617534, -4.62894805 55.07655459, -4.63067565 55.07719054, -4.63218879 55.07774751, -4.63603734 55.0783822, -4.63636727 55.07929898)))"
)), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: @Ronak Shah added the input

Comment: Does the `dput` output work for you? Are you able to copy it? For me it is giving `Error: unexpected symbol in:` error.

Comment: Yes it gives error if copy and run again, but when i load it it is fine